# dpkg -S not showing all files in package

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I've been using `dpkg -S <package_name>` to list the contents of a package. Sometimes I pipe to `grep bin` to quickly scan for executables.

I just ran into a case where this didn't work out for me:

```
$ which virtualenv
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
Reading package lists... Done
...
Setting up python-virtualenv (1.7.1.2-1) ...
$ which virtualenv
/usr/bin/virtualenv
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/virtualenv 
python-virtualenv: /usr/bin/virtualenv
$ dpkg -S python-virtualenv | grep bin
$
```

`/usr/bin/virtualenv` seems to be provided by `python-virtualenv`, but isn't listed in the package contents provided by `dpkg -S`. All the while, passing `/usr/bin/virtualenv` to `dpkg -S` returns that the file comes from `python-virtualenv`. Can you all explain this?

Comment: -S shows which package provides a file. it doesn't show the contents of a package. At least not in ubuntu 12.10 or debian sid which i'm running currently.

Comment: Yeah, I have have been confused by the `man` entry. So, when `-S` appears to be listing package contents, it's really just listing files in packages that match the path-spec I'm providing?

Comment: Yes, it appears the correct switch is -L. Yikes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from that comment (that dpkg -S only shows what package provides a specified file):

Yeah, exactly. so if you go dpkg -S /bin/bash it will report the bash package, and if you do dpkg -S bash (assuming /bin is in your path) it will do the same.

Also check out apt-file, you have to install it first on most distro's but then you can run 'apt-file list ' and it will show the contents for anything in the repositories you have set up; i.e. you don't have to install it first.